# wNumb change specific value (add postfix to specific value)?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, formatting, number-formatting, nouislider

I am trying to make a slider from 0-2000, where 2000 displays as "2000+", encapsulating everything >=2000.

My encoder looks like this:

```
encoder: function(a) {
    a == 2000 ? a = a + '+' : null;
    return a;
}
```

However, this returns `false` when `a=2000`. I take it this is because `a` needs to be an integer, not a string. How can I conditionally add a postfix, then?

Comment: Rather than `null`, and variable assignment, why not: `a += a > 2000 ? '+' : '';` ? I suspect, but don't have time to verify, that you're effectively returning `null` in every non `a == 2000` scenario.

Comment: it does not work to return an integer with a `+` suffix.

Comment: Really, @Nina? I've never had an issue concatenating a string to a number before (when I've deliberately wanted a string as the result).

Comment: @NinaScholz Yup, you're right. David Thomas: I believe wnumb is explicitly looking for a number, not a string, so `a + '+'` returns false. I am specifically asking how to conditionally suffix something inside the wnumb syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this issue and solved it by using wNumb's edit option.
Not perfect because it checks after all formatting but does the job.

```
format: wNumb({
    prefix: '$',
    decimals: 0,
    thousand: ',',
    edit: function( value ) {
        return (value == '$2,000') ? '$2,000+' : value;
    }
})
```